# Is motherboard built-in (onboard) graphics with 256 MB memory sufficient to support a screen with resolution 1080x1920?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, motherboard

My Intel (DG33) motherboard has 256MB built in graphics memory. I want to buy a monitor whose resolution is 1080*1920. To support this resolution, do I have to buy a graphics card or built in motherboard memory would be enough?

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: @Mark Szymanski: Actually this is not shopping question. I just want to know that whether my motherboard graphics memory is enough for 1080*1920 resolution monitor.

Comment: You said "do I have to by a graphics card" therefore making it a shopping question. If you get rid of that part, it is no longer a shopping question and is perfectly fine on this site.

Comment: No, "what graphics card do I need to buy?" would be a product recommendation question. "Do I need to buy something more?" is not a product recommendation question, it is asking about *whether* one needs to buy something. (Yes, I know this question is old, but I'm leaving this as it got bumped to the front page.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you'll you be doing with your system. For gaming, this is definitely not enough. If you're only browsing and doing stuff like that, you should be fine.

However you can get a real cheap graphics card for about 50$ these days.

Comment: i am not a gamer. Just browsing and some programming software. I do open a lot of programs simultaneously. Would it be a problem?

Comment: For graphics no, for system memory, you bet. If you have a lot of modern IDE's for programming and the like you might need in the least 2 GB of RAM memory and a recommened quantity of 4 GB.

Comment: @questionBot, he's got have RAM. I'm pretty sure he only means his onboard Graphcis Memory. In which case, you'll be fine @Riyad Parvez